# Converting string date in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I'm getting a string date from a JSON object. I need to convert the date

`"2018-05-18T04:00:00.000Z"` to.  `May 18 , 2018`

I tried using the Date() constructor but I wasn't successful.

I've heard of `Intl.DateTimeFormat` but I don't understand the documentation. Any help and explanation is appreaiated .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to do this purely with JavaScript, including parsing with Date() and, depending on your browser support requirements, format with [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

The second example (commented out) just shows how it can work with a specific locale (as a string, though that can be an array of such strings).

```js
function formatDate(string){
    var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    return new Date(string).toLocaleDateString([],options);
}
var dateString = "2018-05-18T04:00:00.000Z"
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = formatDate(dateString);
 
// You could also provide specific locale, if needed. For example:
//function formatDate(string){
//    var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
//    return new Date(string).toLocaleDateString('en-US',options);
//}
```

```html
<div id="results"</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer. The answer included the day but I guess I can just exclude it. Your explanation was straightforward as well.

Comment: The format of the result of the above is dependent on the default language for the implementation, so it may not be "May 18, 2018".

Answer (score 16):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) to do this.

```
const date = moment("2018-05-18T04:00:00.000Z").format('DD MMM, YYYY');
console.log(date);
// May 18, 2018
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekjpqsx8/).

Comment: I also like this solution because of its simplicity! A vote for your contribution!

Answer (score 6):

You've created a new Date object correctly and JavaScript stored the correct date. The issue has to do with Locale. In this next line of code, JS has created and stored that exact time. But when we ask for an output from JS we usually get exactly what we ask. From you're example, you've asked for the date based upon a locale that is most likely in the USA. So this:

```
new Date('2018-05-18T04:00:00Z').toLocaleString(); //(or .toString()
```

will give you exactly the result you ask, which is a UTC time shifted to a different locale (I've left the time on for demonstration).

On the other hand, using this:

```
new Date('2018-05-18T04:00:00Z').toUTCString();
```

Will produce the result you expect because it enforces the correct locale to be UTC.

```js
document.querySelector('#a').innerText = new Date('2018-05-18T04:00:00Z').toString();
document.querySelector('#b').innerText = new Date('2018-05-18T04:00:00Z').toUTCString();
```

```html
Incorrect: <p id="a"></p>
<hr>
Correct: <p id="b"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is:

let date = new Date(string);

let readableDate = date.toDateString();